# JSON key value to CSV columns that has data init

Tags: python, json, api, csv, python-2.6

The csv file having json's in each row but in one column in the below format:

```
╔═══╦══════════════════════╗
║   ║ A                    ║
╠═══╬══════════════════════╣
║ 2 ║ {"discover":"123"}   ║
║ 3 ║ {"offer":"321"}      ║
║ 4 ║ {"roadmap":"788789"} ║
║ 5 ║ {"nebravvska":"890"} ║
╚═══╩══════════════════════╝
```

I want the above JSON key and value to be written to each rows in csv col1 and col2 without replacing the existing data. Ohio and california is the existing data.

**Expected output:**

```
╔═══╦════════════════╦══════════╗
║   ║ A              ║ B        ║
╠═══╬════════════════╬══════════╣
║ 1 ║     discover   ║ 123      ║
║ 3 ║     offer      ║ 321      ║
║ 4 ║     roadmap    ║ 78890    ║
║ 5 ║     nebrask    ║ 890      ║
║ 6 ║     ohio       ║ hjsd8943 ║
║ 7 ║     california ║ 68yubkj  ║
╚═══╩════════════════╩══════════╝
```

Im using pycharm 2.6. My code below is writing key and value to one column

```
    ╔═══╦════════════════╗
    ║   ║ A              ║
    ╠═══╬════════════════╣
    ║ 1 ║ discover 123   ║
    ║ 2 ║ offer 321      ║
    ║ 3 ║ roadmap 788789 ║
    ║ 4 ║ nebravvska 890 ║
    ╚═══╩════════════════╝

    with open("JSONsinfile.csv","rU") as infile:
            with open("output.csv","a+") as outfile:
                writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=' ')
                for line in infile:
                    d = json.loads(line)
                    writer.writerows(d.items())

        infile.close()
        outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Using "pandas" library you can have following solution:

1)- Install pandas

```
pip install pandas
```

2)- script:

```
import csv, json
import csv
import pandas as pd

inp_csv = pd.read_csv("JSONsinfile.csv")
lst_of_dict = inp_csv['{"discover":"123"}'].tolist()
mydict={key:value for elem in lst_of_dict for key,value in eval(elem).items()}

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: Is this line  "lst_of_dict = inp_csv['{"discover":"123"}'].tolist()" taking all the Json into list or only a one JSON

Comment: this line is creating a list where "discover":"123" has been taken as coloumn name as its the first element, we can have any coloumn name. it is taking ALL THE JSON INTO THE LIST out of the same coloumn.

Comment: mydict= {key:value for elem in lst_of_dict for key,value in eval(elem).items()}
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax This erroring out for syntax error after mydict

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read in the existing data if you want to preserve it:

**Code:**

```
import csv
import json

# get current data
with open('file1', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    in_data = dict((row[0], row[1]) for row in reader)

    # if you have python 2.7+ this also works, and looks nicer :-)
    # in_data = {row[0]: row[1] for row in reader}

with open("file2", "rU") as infile, open("file3", "wb") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=' ')
    for line in infile:
        d = json.loads(line)
        writer.writerows(d.items())
        for key in d:
            if key in in_data:
                del in_data[key]

    # write out any pre-existing unchanged data
    writer.writerows(in_data.items())
```

**Existing Data (file1):**

```
discover 123
offer 321
roadmap 78890
nebrask 890
ohio hjsd8943
california 68yubkj
```

**Incoming Json (file2):**

```
{"discover":"123"}
{"offer":"321"}
{"roadmap":"788789"}
{"nebravvska":"890"}
```

**Results (file3):**

```
discover 123
offer 321
roadmap 788789
nebravvska 890
california 68yubkj
nebrask 890
ohio hjsd8943
```

Comment: I tried this code in 2.7 it is giving syntax error as below 
in_data = {row[0]: row[1] for row in reader}

Comment: I just cut and paste that code as a block and it runs fine in 2.7 at this end.  Are you sure you don't have 2.6?  Try :`in_data = dict((row[0], row[1]) for row in reader)`

Comment: I'm doing this is 2.6. I take that word "2.7" back sorry for the typo. I'm doing Below is the error in 2.6 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 "/Users/CSVJson to csv_stack.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/CSVJson to csv_stack.py", line 8, in <module>
    in_data = dict((row[0], row[1]) for row in reader)
  File "/Users/CSVJson to csv_stack.py", line 8, in <genexpr>
    in_data = dict((row[0], row[1]) for row in reader)
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That indicates that the reader is not reading the file into two columns.  How is your file column separated?  You will need to tell the csv reader what it needs to read that file correctly.

Comment: IN the file JSON are like this in col1 cellA {"discover":"123"} col1 cell2 {"offer":"321"}.

Comment: That is file1, the existing csv, not the json.  Look at my example.

Comment: my code is writing both the key and value to col1cellA like this "discover 123". My desired output should be writing key and value to separate column. **COL1      COL2**
                 discover    123

Answer (score 1):

The code below will write keys in one column and values in other column, you have to create a dictionary after reading the csv like

```
mydict = {"discover":"123","offer:321"}

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)e 
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```